# Error after approved: no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Tags: iphone

My app was approved (release date in the future) but when I try to download using the promo code, I get this error "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application"  What am I doing wrong?   Do I need to change something and resubmit? 
Thanks in advance for any insight into this issue.
Jason